# HTML confusion with Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm following thenewboston's tutorials on youtube and after compiling my code I get no errors.

I'm trying to print the "Generic Line List" and all the links following that list;can be found at the bottom of this link
http://playrustwiki.com/wiki/List_of_Items

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages: #makes our pages change everytime
        url = 'http://playrustwiki.com/wiki/List_of_Items' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text) #find all the links in soup or all the titles
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'a href'}): #links are a for anchors in HTML
        href = link.get('href') # href attribute
        print(href)
        page += 1

trade_spider(1)
```

I've tried different HTML attributes but I think thats where my confusion starts. I can't find the correct attribute to call for my scraper or I'm calling the wrong attribute.

Please help~

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here would be to find the element that has `Generic line list` text. Then, find the next `ul` sibling via [`find_next_sibling()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) and get all links inside via `find_all()`:

```
h3 = soup.find('h3', text='Generic Line List')
generic_line_list = h3.find_next_sibling('ul')
for link in generic_line_list.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> url = 'http://playrustwiki.com/wiki/List_of_Items'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
>>>
>>> h3 = soup.find('h3', text='Generic Line List')
>>> generic_line_list = h3.find_next_sibling('ul')
>>> for link in generic_line_list.find_all('a', href=True):
...     print(link['href'])
... 
/wiki/Wood_Barricade
/wiki/Wood_Shelter
...
/wiki/Uber_Hunting_Bow
/wiki/Cooked_Chicken_Breast
/wiki/Anti-Radiation_Pills
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks for the fast reply. I understand your code iterates through if   href is true and thus prints all those found. Appreciate it mucho!